# How do I make a custom belongs_to association with a different foreign_key display as the association name when rendering as JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, rails-activerecord

I'm fairly new to rails and have 5 associations made through belongs_to on my Champion model that connects to the Ability model which has a has_one association back to the Champion model.

These 5 associations use a foreign key that matches to the association name plus "_id". When I go to render the page, I see the the "_id" values as integers appearing, but want those to show up as the actual record. So instead of just showing an integer, it would show the full Ability record with all of its fields.

Here is my Champion.rb model:

```
class Champion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :q_id,
                  :w_id,
                  :e_id,
                  :r_id,
                  :passive_id

  belongs_to :q, :class_name => "Ability", :foreign_key => "q_id"
  belongs_to :w, :class_name => "Ability", :foreign_key => "w_id"
  belongs_to :e, :class_name => "Ability", :foreign_key => "e_id"
  belongs_to :r, :class_name => "Ability", :foreign_key => "r_id"
  belongs_to :passive, :class_name => "Ability", :foreign_key => "passive_id"
end
```

And the ability.rb model:

```
class Ability < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :champion
end
```

And the controller displaying the model :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def show_all
    load_models

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { "champions" => @champions } }
    end
  end

  protected
  def load_models
    @champions = Champion.all
  end
end
```

So how do I set it up so that the JSON shows "q", "w", "e", "r", and "passive" without "_id", and displays the entire Ability record? Right now it only shows the actual database fields containing the ids, but does not display the records like I want. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @champions.to_json(:include => {:q => {}, :w => {}}) }
end
```

I might recommend looking into something like [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) though. It will make it cleaner to handle these more complicated json responses. There's a good Railscast on it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl).